# Can I configure Infinispan to use JavaSerializationMarshaller() on a specific cache and use protobufs on other caches?

Tags: java, serialization, infinispan, infinispan-10

I am attempting to upgrade from `Infinispan 8.2.11.Final` to `Infinispan 10.1.8.Final`.  Infinispan now uses protocol buffers by default.  The Infinispan cache is used by Hibernate and also contains some application objects.

I can set the global marshaller as follows:

```
    holder.getGlobalConfigurationBuilder()
          .serialization()
          .marshaller( new JavaSerializationMarshaller() )
          .whiteList().addClasses( CLASSES );
```

However, if I do this it will be necessary to whitelist all the hibernate classes (e.g. `org.hibernate.cache.internal.CacheKeyImplementation` and others).

Is it possible to set the marshaller on the caches used for application objects so that I can continue to use Java serialization for my application objects while allowing Hibernate to use protobuf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The marshaller is global to all caches.

You can add the Hibernate package to the white list by doing:

```
.whiteList().addRegexps("org\\.hibernate.*");
```

Check for more info in Infinispan docs [here](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#java_serialization) and [here](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#deserialization_whitelist).

offtopic: the last stable release is 11.0.1.Final.

Comment: I was hoping to limit the whitelist as there could be deserialization gadgets in Hibernate, but I think this will be very difficult without knowing all the internals.